# Authentication between my services hosted on Google Cloud, using service accounts & signed JWT

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a .NET Core API that will use OAuth2 for authorizing API calls. I've managed to successfully use Microsoft Identity Web API authentication, I can successfully play with my API via Swagger, however, my API will be hosted in Google Cloud and other services (also hosted there) will be using my API, it seems to be a good idea to use GCloud Service Accounts for authorization.

I've been [following](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#python) for instructions and the results leave me confused.

As mentioned in the link above, I've added SecurityDefinition and SecurityRequirement to my specification file. Code:

```
            var openApiOAuthFlowExtensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>();
            openApiOAuthFlowExtensions.Add("x-google-issuer", new OpenApiString("test-api-consumer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"));
            openApiOAuthFlowExtensions.Add("x-google-jwks_uri", new OpenApiString("https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test-api-consumer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"));
            openApiOAuthFlowExtensions.Add("x-google-audiences", new OpenApiString("https://my-project.ew.r.appspot.com/"));

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("service-1-auth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "service-1-auth",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                {
                    Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "readAccess", "Access read operations" },
                            { "writeAccess", "Access write operations" }
                        },
                        Extensions = openApiOAuthFlowExtensions
                    }
                },
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "service-1-auth"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                }
            });
```

That's what I get in my swagger.json file:

```
  "securitySchemes": {
  "service-1-auth": {
    "type": "oauth2",
    "flows": {
      "implicit": {
        "authorizationUrl": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "scopes": {
          "readAccess": "Access read operations",
          "writeAccess": "Access write operations"
        },
        "x-google-issuer": "test-api-consumer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test-api-consumer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "x-google-audiences": "https://my-project.ew.r.appspot.com/"
      }
    }
  }
}
},
  "security": [
    {
      "service-1-auth": [ ]
    }
  ]
```

Then I wrote a Python script as following [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request) step and all I am getting is `401 Unauthorized`... The JWT token generated by the script is exactly what I wanted, I've checked the decoded values many times.

What am I doing wrong? How should I debug here..? My gut feeling says that there's something wrong with the API configuration or that I simply don't know that I'm missing some crucial steps. I get the same results locally and on test environment. It's my first time implementing API authorization on my own so I'm pretty lost here. What's even more confusing is that I followed the guidelines step by step and still have no result. Maybe I use wrong packages? It doesn't make sense though.

I'd highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Do you protect app engine with IAP?